# Prevent workbook from switching to newly imported sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a work book that import a sheet through a control button. Currently the workbook is switching to the newly imported sheet and I would like to prevent that from happening, so that is stays on the sheet with the control button.

Here is my code:

```
Sub ImportSheet()
    Dim sImportFile As String, sFile As String
    Dim sThisBk As Workbook
    Dim vfilename As Variant
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set sThisBk = ActiveWorkbook
    sImportFile = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
    FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Workbooks, *.xls; *.xlsx", Title:="Open Workbook")
If sImportFile = "False" Then
    MsgBox "No File Selected!"
    Exit Sub

Else
    vfilename = Split(sImportFile, "\")
    sFile = vfilename(UBound(vfilename))
    Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:=sImportFile
    Set wbBk = Workbooks(sFile)
    With wbBk
        If SheetExists(sWSName) Then
            Set wsSht = .Sheets(sWSName)
            wsSht.Copy after:=sThisBk.Sheets("Sheet3")
        Else
            MsgBox "There is no sheet with name :Raw_Data in:" & vbCr & .Name
        End If
        wbBk.Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

Private Function SheetExists(sWSName) As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    sWSName = InputBox("Enter sheet name")
    Set ws = Worksheets(sWSName)
    If Not ws Is Nothing Then SheetExists = True
End Function
```

I could not work out where in the code it is switching, perhaps I need to put some code in to make it remain static on the import?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think it automatically happens when you copy the worksheet. You could go about this by selecting the original sheet at the end of your sub.

Comment: Good idea, it did the job!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your declare block

```
Dim sThisSht As Worksheet
```

And this where you also set the `sThisBk`

```
Set sThisSht = ActiveWorksheet
```

And then before you revert `ScreenUpdating = True`, add this to return to the active sheet set at the start:

```
sThisSht.Activate
```